# EditText inputType сперва числа, потом буквы

Tags: android, android-edittext

Нужно сделать поля `EditText` с возможностью вводить номер дома и квартиры.

Номера бывают целочисленные, но встречаются варианты с буквами и дробями: 7А, 10/4 и тому подобное.

Понятно, что можно просто сделать строку, но хотелось бы сперва отобразить числовую клавиатуру (так как чаще всего просто число), но при этом иметь возможность переключения.

Подходящего варианта в списке предлагаемых я не нашел, может кто-то подскажет.

Comment: С чем конкретно у вас возникла проблема? Вы можете динамически менять `inputType` у EditText, например `editText.inputType = TYPE_CLASS_TEXT`, чтобы вводить текст или `editText.inputType = TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER`, чтобы вводить числа. Сделайте кнопку и меняйте.

Answer (score 0):

В Андроид можно динамически менять `inputType` у виджета `EditText`. Предположим, у вас есть `EditText` с `inputType = "number"` и две кнопки:

```xml
<EditTextinputType
    ...
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:hint="Номер дома"
    android:inputType="number" />

<Button
    ...
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:text="Установить текстовый ввод" />

<Button
    ...
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:text="Установить числовой ввод" />
```

По нажатию на первую кнопку будем менять `inputType` на `TYPE_CLASS_TEXT`:

```kotlin
button1.setOnClickListener {
    editText.inputType = TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
}
```

А при нажатии на вторую кнопку будем менять `inputType` обратно на `TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER`:

```kotlin
button2.setOnClickListener {
    editText.inputType = TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
}
```

Comment: Это понятно, просто я думал может есть возможность сделать обратное действие от дефолтной клавиатуры. Но вижу что такого решения нет, так что оставлю как есть. Спасибо.

Comment: Если хотите, сделайте переключение по кнопке клавиатуры. Для этого укажите свойство `imeOptions` у `EditText` и реализуйте обработчик `setOnEditorActionListener`. Но в вопросе мало конкретики, поэтому я не совсем понимаю, какое решение вам подойдет, а какое нет. "Иметь возможность переключения" звучит очень абстрактно.